# sql - value is 0 but return empty cell

Tags: mysql

i am currently doing some data testing, so i want to export my file into my local (into excel format) but there is column AGE in my file, where if the age value = 0, it return as blank cell (i want it to return 0) in excel after mapping completed. it return other value accordingly (ex: 1,2,3,4) except for 0 value. i am sure i should use ISNULL() for this, but i can't get it to save 0 instead of blank cell.

PS/: AGE is a calculation of a YEAR
deprStartDate is a VARCHAR column

my code currently

`year(getdate()) - CAST(ISNULL(right(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(pcld.[deprStartDate], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''))),4),0) AS VARCHAR) as [AGE]`

other things that ive tried so far is using COALESCE

`year(getdate()) - COALESCE(CAST(right(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(pcld.[deprStartDate], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''))),4) AS INT),'') as [AGE]`

i am sure this is the right function for getting the 0, but i am not sure if i did in the correct way.. Need someone to help me out, cause i am really new to SQL. Thank a lot.

Comment: Try using IFNULL instead!

Comment: ok i will try it, but base on my code, is it in correct format os using ISNULL? @cdaiga

Comment: Too much missing info. What is the column type of deprStartDate? By age, do you mean days, months, years?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: updated, you may recheck, thanks. @SloanThrasher

Comment: it is actually a calculation for year @SloanThrasher

Comment: Dates should be stored as dates, timestamp, etc, not varchar. If you make the column type a date type, then there are lots of great functions you can use on them. Storing as a varchar will lead to all sorts of problems, and possibly corrupt data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "0" to be returned when the value is "blank" (presumably `NULL`), then put that value in the `COALESCE()`:

```
year(getdate()) - COALESCE(CAST(right(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(pcld.[deprStartDate], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''))),4) AS INT), '0') as [AGE]
```

I cannot speak to the rest of your logic, but the value should be `'0'`, not `''`.

Comment: tried '0', ' ', and also 0. didn't work out.. is it possibly cause by my logic? thanks for your feedback @Gordon Linoff